# Вызывает ли контроллер Dispose для своих полей и свойств?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dispose

Если в контроллере затребовать через конструктор EF-контекст и положить его в поле, то при завершении запроса, на этом контексте вызовется Dispose?

Comment: Нет конечно. Dispose вызывается в двух случаях - вами или GC при сборке мусора. К тому же ни один класс (кроме специально написанных вами), не будет ничего делать с экземплярами без вашего ведома.

Comment: @aepot разве GC вызывает Dispose? GC ведь вызывает Finallizer

Comment: @Aarnihauta а Finalizer вызывает Dispose :) Но вы правы конечно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такое правило - утилизировать объект должен создатель объекта, если особо не оговорено другое.

В частности, когда вы запрашиваете зависимость через параметр конструктора, утилизация зависимости является ответственностью передавшего её. И все достаточно продвинутые системы внедрения зависимостей это правило поддерживают. Однако, для надёжности надо смотреть документацию на конкретную систему внедрения зависимостей.

В частности, используемый вами ASP.NET MVC... вообще не поддерживает внедрение зависимостей через конструктор.